# Is my personal thoughts of interest to others?

Tags: discussion

Salam! I have been told that answers here are expected to have citations from Quran, sunnah, Fatwas from reliable scholars, or other reliable source.

If I am here by interest and to learn, then it means that I can not refere to any citations, as I don't know them yet. Thus I can not utter my opinions or my questions without this knowledge. How can I feel welcome here on these terms.

I thought this was a place to learn and to understand.

If personal opinions are not accepted as answers to specific questions, then the question must already have an answer? How can I find that, if not within myself.

If I am to learn, so then guide me to the right citations so I can use them.

Of course my answer is all self opinion, and how can I edit my answer and provide citations to back it up if I don't know how. Should I not share my thoughts without the total knowledge of the quran?

I was interested to learn and provide my thoughts and get advise referring to ccurrent issues. Without questions and answers, which demands knowledge of citations regarding the issue itself, how can I then learn from that?

If I am totally wrong about this, then I assume that this forum is not for me. To belive or try, is not to know and teach.

Please let me know what the quaran says about this. This is a forum for those who are interested. The interpretation to push away people because they can not refer to what they don't know, but wish to learn, is that the way of saying welcome and join us?

If question are about how to deal with a western cultures business elements, it is important to let people the interpretation at a basic level. If not, they will never understand.

All of us have a capacity of thinking, a capacity of interpretation and a capacity of judgement. Is it not the way of Islam to have an open mind on this`?

Sorry about all questions and personal thoughts. I hope you understand my point of view. If my thoughts are not welcome here, I will immediatly leave and cause no more trouble due to my incompetense.

My name is Ali Kunt, my father was a muslim. He is not alive. Would he reject me in my way of searching?

However, I will try to find the proper dictations to refere to.

Answer (score 2):

Your post is really disjointed and all over the place - I guess the only reasonable way to answer it is point by point.

1) In general you don't need citations to ask questions (referring to the parts where you said you want to learn). The only situation I can think of where you need citations in the question is when you are asking about some lesser-known practice or belief.

2) Yes, we are here to ask questions that have answers.

3) We are here to create a repository of answers *about Islam* that are of use to everyone who is interested. Our personal opinions are not, in general, of use to very many people, and so we require that answers come from accepted sources of knowledge about Islam.

4) No one's asking you to refer to what you don't know - however if you don't know something, you probably shouldn't be answering that question. It just adds to the noise. The point of the website is this: if some person somewhere has a question about Islam, they should be able to arrive at this website and find a good expert answer, not several amateur answers.

5) Your thoughts are welcome here as long as they **answer the question** or **ask a well-defined question** about Islam in a way that is beneficial and generalizable to others.

Comment: 1) This answer demands a better definition of what is  lesser-known practice or belief. Thus, it will need a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In the blog post [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) — the whole being highly-recommend reading — Robert Cartaino refers to the "Back It Up!" principle, which he explains thus:

> Back It Up! means that your answers must be based on either:
>
> - Something that happened to you personally
> - Something you can back up with a reference
>
> They talk about how “opinion, by itself, is noise.” They’re not saying
>   that subjective opinions are to be avoided; they’re attempting to mold
>   and shape their inherently subjective Q&A into something constructive,
>   informative and helpful.

The Stack Exchange philosophy is to build a library of high-quality questions and answers; one aspect of a high-quality answer is not only that it  answers the question asked, but also that it does so in a focused and useful manner for the questioner as well as all future visitors.

Anybody can have an opinion.  Personal opinions, however, don't just form out of thin air; they have to come from somewhere.  And what makes such an opinion *useful* is where it comes from:

- Was the opinion based on relevant personal experiences?  *Describe those*.
- Was the opinion based on something you read?  *Reference that*.
- Was the opinion based on meticulous research and personal interpretation?  *Explain that*.

Basically, if you feel your personal opinion is a valuable answer to the question, be prepared to build a case for it in your post.  Then the community at large can judge how useful (or not useful) it actually is through voting.

And since a library of high-quality questions and answers requires both high-quality answers *and* high-quality questions, you can just [Ask a Question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if there's anything you don't actually know.  And if you're just looking to share your thoughts with others in a more casual setting, [the Islam.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is open to all users [who have earned 20 reputation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat).

Comment: The source of opinions is based on your capacity of interpretation and knowledge and also buildt upon subtle issues. out of thin air comes no opinions, that is clear.
Opinions on opinions is a way to achieve understanding, but judgement of opinions by "experts", will lead nowhere.
Thanks for my short visit here. I have learned a lot, but not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this stack exchange is for learning about islam, You can ask any valid  answerable question related to islam

But if you gonna answer a questions, you should have enough knowledge in that subject. Personal interpretation of islamic laws are dangerous

Comment: I understand. I just don't know the right interpretations.
That is why I have my own. Thank you for advising me!